# Meta are moved to body

Tags: templating, meta

I am getting some global entries from the CMS that I want to use as meta-tags content.

When I load the page I see in the inspection that the meta-tags are moved inside the body.  When I remove the dynamic meta-tags and use only the hardcoded, everything is ok.

I have something like that in the head:

```
{% set metadata = craft.globals.getSetByHandle('metadata') %}

<title>{{ metadata.title }}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{{ metadata.description }}">
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ metadata.keywords}}">
```

Why the meta-tags are moved? How can I fix that? Is it a Craft issue or a Twig issue or my mistake?

Comment: OT you can remove that `getSetByHandle` line completely as global sets get loaded automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was caused by a secret character, the character was not visible in code but it was noticed in the w3c validator for html.

[image]

So after removing that character issue solved.

Comment: Funny enough the whitespace character was even in your code example in your original question causing Markdown to freak out and not want to treat that line as a code block. Glad you got it sorted!